# DIH delta import for multiple fields index from mysql

Tags: solr, dih

What is pk in solr DIH delta import?  I am trying to delta index multiple fields in solr?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is whatever field you specify in your schema.xml file as the id field.

Comment: plz look at the code above and see if there is anything wroong?

Comment: Hi

i indexed data and it was successful(46 documents).  Now when i do query to show me all the documents(/select?q=*:*) It only show me numFound=9.  In my mysql data all the fields will null value it does not show me those documents, how can i fix it so that it show me all the documents? any hint what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

It is a name of Solr field that serves as a unique key for that record. You define your mapping of source to that Solr column and then - after mapping - Solr checks its presence and values based on the pk field you specified.

It is different from primaryKey because you may be generating primaryKey or it may not be suitable somehow. But it could be same. I think the clearest Wiki explanation may be in [the example for HttpDataSource](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HttpDataSource_Example).

I believe, you may also be able to define a compound pk for when you are flattening inner source entries into one Solr entry.

Comment: I am trying to index fields from two tables. both of their primary key is: id. I have included data-config file above can you tell me what m i doing wrong. plz. and do i need to include field pk in schema?

Comment: I think you need to remap id for the gadget_lang table to something like gadget_lang_id in Solr. Then, the pk for the child table is gadget_lang_id.

Comment: remap in Solr, what do u mean? do i have to add a field name gadget_lang_id in my schema file?

Comment: I think so. And then have the line in DIH's inner entity: <field column="gadget_lang_id" name="id" />

Comment: Hi

i indexed data and it was successful(46 documents).  Now when i do query to show me all the documents(/select?q=*:*) It only show me numFound=9.  In my mysql data all the fields will null value it does not show me those documents, how can i fix it so that it show me all the documents? any hint what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your delta-query for the child entity. You have given,

```
deltaQuery="select id from cc_gadget_lang where '${cc_gadget.last_modified_date}' > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
```

I think the where condition in the above query validates to TRUE always and there is no specific purpose of having that.

The Solution I would suggest is to have a separate **"last_modified_date" field in the "cc_gadget_lang"** table in your database and use that in the delta query of your child entity.

I also believe that there is **no need to have the "pk" of the child entity in your schema** file because, they are stored and used temporarily during delta-imports and do not require to be stored permanently in Index.

Comment: Hi

i indexed data and it was successful(46 documents).  Now when i do query to show me all the documents(/select?q=*:*) It only show me numFound=9.  In my mysql data all the fields will null value it does not show me those documents, how can i fix it so that it show me all the documents? any hint what i should do?